# Firebird Database Split String on Field

Tags: sql, firebird

Currently working with a Firebird 1.5 database and attempting to pull the data in the correct format natively with SQL.

Consider the following database:

```
ID | Full Name
 1   Jon Doe
 2   Sarah Lee
```

What I am trying to achieve is a simple split on the full name field (space) within a query.

```
ID | First Name | Last Name
1     Jon          Doe
2     Sarah        Lee
```

The issue faced is Firebird POSITION() was introduced in v2.0.  Is there any known workaround to split on a space that anyone has come across?

Much appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Are you allowed to use SP?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem: but seriously: upgrade already, since the release of 1.5 the Firebird project has released 2.0, 2.1, 2.5 and 3.0 is around the corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Firebird 1.5, a solution is to find a UDF that either combines both functions, or provides the position (I don't use UDFs, so I am not sure if one already exists). If none is available, you might have to write one.

The other solution is to write a stored procedure for this functionality, see for example: [Position of substring function in SP](https://web.archive.org/web/20180322180542/http://mujweb.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_code_string.htm#_code_strpos)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Pos (SubStr VARCHAR(100), Str VARCHAR(100))
  RETURNS (Pos INTEGER) AS
DECLARE VARIABLE SubStr2 VARCHAR(201); /* 1 + SubStr-lenght + Str-length */
DECLARE VARIABLE Tmp VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
  IF (SubStr IS NULL OR Str IS NULL)
  THEN BEGIN Pos = NULL; EXIT; END

  SubStr2 = SubStr || '%';
  Tmp = '';
  Pos = 1;
  WHILE (Str NOT LIKE SubStr2 AND Str NOT LIKE Tmp) DO BEGIN
    SubStr2 = '_' || SubStr2;
    Tmp = Tmp || '_';
    Pos = Pos + 1;
  END

  IF (Str LIKE Tmp) THEN Pos = 0;
END
```

This example (taken from the link) can be extended to then use [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) to split on the space.

For searching on a single character like a space, a simpler solution can probably be devised than above stored procedure. For your exact needs you might need to write a selectable stored procedure specifically for this purpose.

However, upgrading your database to Firebird 2.5 will give you much more [powerful internal functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions) that simplify this query (and your life)!

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to split a full name string to first and last name and I used the following SQL statements in firebird 2.1 Database:

**Patients** is the table name.
The **Name** field holds the full name string e.g.: "Jon Doe". The **FIRST_NAME** field will store the first name and the **LAST_NAME** field the last name

First get the first name (string part before the first space) and execute a TRIM UPDATE statement to remove any spaces.

```
UPDATE "Patients" SET "Patients".FIRST_NAME = (SUBSTRING("Patients"."Name" FROM 1 FOR (POSITION(' ' IN "Patients"."Name"))))
UPDATE "Patients" SET "Patients".FIRST_NAME = TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM "Patients".FIRST_NAME)
```

Then get the last name (the string after the first space) and execute a TRIM UPDATE statement to remove any spaces

```
UPDATE "Patients" SET "Patients"."LAST_NAME" = (SUBSTRING("Patients"."Name" FROM (POSITION(' ' IN "Patients"."Name")+1)))
UPDATE "Patients" SET "Patients".LAST_NAME = TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM "Patients".LAST_NAME)
```

The result will be:

```
ID | NAME      | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
1    Jon Doe     Jon          Doe
2    Sarah Lee   Sarah        Lee
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF, but that isn't strictly SQL

you could write a stored procedure to parse and split but thats not strictly SQL either